# Flask .htaccess for FastCGI

Tags: mod-rewrite, fastcgi, flask

I am trying to get my Flask application working on Hostgator shared account. I am having troubles with getting a right configuration of mod_rewrite rules. My `dispatch.fcgi` appears as a part of URL e.g. `www.example.com/dispatch.fcgi/news/`. How can I fix it?

Here is my .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteRule ^(dispatch\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

I tried many variants none of them works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Now it is in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/fastcgi/). Check the "Configuring Apache" section.